# weird bug on release when trying to convert a scientific notation string to a long value in java, android

Tags: android, string, format, locale, scientific-notation

so I have this line of code that converts a scientific notation string to a long value string:

`String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(post.get("date"))));`

but while it works in test mode (debug), it crashes the app in release mode (if I download it from the google play store internal test page).

I'm guessing it is something related to the locale settings since the ide warns me about that, so I tried changing the locale parameter or the `.format()` method but the app still crashes giving me `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.684000811E9"` when I try to parse the long string with `Long.parseLong()` function, so this means the string does not get converted and I can't explain why.

Also note that if I compile the app in release mode using apk method (and not aab), and I install it, the error is not present.